# How to print the SharePoint list using python shaplum module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ntlm-authentication

I am new to python and struggling to over come an issue. My requirement is to copy the item of sharpoint list like 'ID', 'Description' and 'Year' columns data from a  a sharepoint url.

https://test.test1.com/discovery/pmtoolkit/WorkForceManagement/SLP/Lists/slp_references_db/AllItems.aspx

I am using shareplum module for accessing the data and requests_ntlm for authentication.

Authentication is successful and i am getting 200k OK for my auth request.

But i am unable to access the list data itself. Please help me in over coming the issue.

```py
from shareplum import Site
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

username = "Sasken\\test"
password = "test@4321"
site_url = "https://kenpoint.sasken.com/discovery/pmtoolkit/WorkForceManagement/SLP/Lists/slp_references_db/AllItems.aspx"
r = requests.get(site_url, auth=HttpNtlmAuth(site_url + username, password))
print(r.status_code)

sp_list = site_url.List('slp_references_db')

list_data = sp_list.GetListItems()
```

```sh
<ipython-input-141-9baf9625eec7> in <module>()
      9 print(r.status_code)
     10 
---> 11 sp_list = site_url.List('AllItems')
     12 
     13 list_data = sp_list.GetListItems()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'List'
```

Can some one help me in letting me know, what mistake i am doing and how to get rid of this error and copy the list data of each row in to a python list. If it has 100 rows, then create 100 lists of data in python with ID, Description and Year. Later I should be able to use that data for some other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Shareplum package to get SharePoint list items. Kindly refer the below code that helped me with the similar issue.

```
from shareplum import Office365, Site
from shareplum.site import Version
authcookie = Office365("https://yoururl.sharepoint.com/", username=Username, password=Password).GetCookies()
site = Site("https://yoururl.sharepoint.com/sites/site-name", version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
sp_list = site.List('your_list_name')
fields=['ID','Description','Year']
sp_data = sp_list.GetListItems(fields=fields)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm also pretty new to this module and trying to understand, but unfortunately I'm unable to get detailed documentation with examples

Please try using:

```
# this is creating shareplum object

sp_list = site_url.List('slp_references_db')
```

Using the following line you can specify all items or number of rows you want to extract:

```
list_data = sp_list.GetListItems('All Items')
```

Here is a url you can refer to [SharePlum Tutorial](https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)

please do rate if this helps, thanks